# <rich:tabPanel> not switching

Tags: richfaces

I have a `<rich:tabPanel>` and inside it I have three `<rich:tab>`,but tabs are not changing automatically whenever I'm clicking the next button for switching from one tab to another.Validation checking  is performed correctly and I have put condition on rendered property of `<rich:tab>`,that is also working correctly whenever I'm clicking the next Button 2nd tab is comming,but I need to click it through mouse for viewing its components,this should happen automatically as per the property of `<rich:tab>`.

can anyone has any solution to this?

```
<rich:panel header="My Claim > New Claim" headerClass="header-left" style="border:0;text-align:left;width:910px">  
    <rich:tabPanel  selectedTab="#{billController.currentTab}" id="tabPanel">
        <!-- first default panel -->
        <rich:tab header="Step 1" name="fisrt" id="tab1">
            <h:commandButton value="Next" action="#{billcontroller.saveData}"/>
        </rich:tab>  
    </rich:panel>

<rich:tab header="Step 2"  rendered="#{billController.uploadEnabled}" name="second">

</rich:tab>
```

Comment: Can you show your view code?

Comment: Please use the "Code" button to format your code.

Comment: It looks like the seconde `<rich:tab>`is not inside the `<rich:tabPanel>` and also the `<rich:tabPanel>` is not closed...

Comment: no man that is not the case all the tags are closed and all the rich:tab is within rich:tabPanel,but the problem is I need to click on the 2nd rich:tab for viewing its content but it should happen automatically that is the use of rich:tab,do u understood what I'm saying????

Comment: The tag closures don't add up correctly. The rich:panel closes before the rich:tabPanel it contains. Does it even render?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. And in my case a surrounding `<h:body>` solved the problem.

Comment: Surprisingly it helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'switchType=ajax|client|Server', you have missed to include switch type